# DOM not refreshing with Selenium (IE, Chrome and VBA)

Tags: vba, selenium, dom

I'm using Selenium Basic to collect data from a website and store this into a database. The page I'm scraping is dynamic and loads more information as you scroll. I've been able to address most of this by using the implicit/ explicit waits, etc.

I am capturing all the IDs necessary to create the click action, which opens up another javascript popup for me to collect information there. However, even though I've been able to get these new IDs when the page loads by scrolling, when the app uses that new ID to click, I'm getting an error saying  the element cannot be found. This is preventing me from opening up the javascript windows for these newly loaded rows.

When I go to collect this new data, the elements don't exist even though I was able to get the IDs for them. 
When I look at the DOM in the browser and page source, all of it is there, so I don't believe it's an issue of letting the browser load.

I've tried utilizing the wait methods (implicit/explicit)...I've even put in hard 60 second waits through the routine. No matter what I do, the routine bombs out after the first 10 rows because it can't find the elements to the data it found after scrolling. I've also tried this using Chrome as well.

Unfortunately, the website needs to be private, so I can't provide the full code. The issue that's happening comes here:

`driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[contains(text(),'" & DBA!ParseID     & "')]").Click`

The error I get is "Element not found for XPath("//*[contains(text(),'ID12345"')]

ParseID is the ID found from parsing elements within the body tag. So, I am able to collect all the IDs after loading all the data, but when it goes to click using the above code, it only works for the initial 10 rows. Everything loaded after that will not work (even though they've been loaded in the Browser for quite some time).

What I should be getting is, say 20 IDs which can create 20 clicks to javascript pop-ups to get more information. However, I am getting 20 IDs but the ability to only click on the first 10, even though I've loaded the entire page.

Comment: Perhaps your code trial `//*[contains(text(),'" & DBA!ParseID     & "')]` and the error `Element not found for XPath("//*[contains(text(),'ID12345"')]` doesn't match.

Comment: Can you provide the url and more of the script?

Comment: I did think of that. Triple checked; they match.  If only it were that easy!

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot provide the URL because it has personal information on it. I will post more code once I get to the office. Again, the code seems to work up until the page loads more data. Then it's as is if it never updated the DOM.

Comment: Is there a viewport where items need to be in focus in order to work?

Comment: I assumed this too, though I'm not sure if it is necessary.  I've even used sendkeys to scroll so these entries would be totally in focus when the routine is to process them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue hasn't been resolved the way I initially expected, but I've accomplished what I needed through a different and more efficient way.

First, when I researched this further by removing certain IDs in my loop, I noticed that this really didn't have much to do with data updating in the DOM or browser, but rather the ID itself not being found by a (still) unknown reason. It actually seems very arbitrary why it's bombing out. The ID matches the ID in the DOM, but when the string is being moved to the XPath, it can't find it in the DOM. I'm not sure why this would occur unless the string is breaking when being passed somehow, but I'll just let that one remain mysterious until someone smarter comes along!

What I did to accomplish what I needed is loop through the actual class N times, and pull the elements I needed within the classes. Rather than use the ID above as a unique identifier, I used the count of class web elements as the identifier. This worked with 90% less code.

Thank you all!